# Browser back button does not move to the previous View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I am using views concept in my asp.net form control.my first view consist of a form to capture user details.when user press continue it will move to the second view.
The problem is ,When user press the back button of the browser from the second view it doesn't move the the previous view instead move to the previous page in the browser history.

I wanted to move to the first view with the existing data in the form,when user press the back button of the browser.

Comment: Browsers store only accessed urls in the history. They do not know what the notion of *view* means. A view is an ASP.NET MVC specific notion. A view is always served through controller actions so you should be thinking in terms of controller actions when working with the browser history, not views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform a full `page postback` I guess, so that at client end your previous view will be saved in browser's history.

Comment: This full postback works and it goes back to the previous view.But it does not hold the viewstates.The form values got deleted when come back.Is there any solution for that or view have to hold the viewsates and load them back to the form when the page loads ?

Comment: When users click on back button, your page is picked up from cache so your `viewstate` will not be found there, I guess. One solution could be providing your user a BACK button from where user can go back with a `postback` & don't have to press browser's back button, but still user can press back button of browser & we would end up from where we had begun.